# Including nested objects in the JSON of a Spring Boot application

Tags: java, spring-boot, jackson

Can anyone guide me on how to nest the **JSON** object **Activation** under the **JSON** object **Data**.

See my **JSON** below:

```
{
    "status": "Success",
    "DATA": {
        "aid": "0",
        "app": "OASIS_EDGE",
        "actkey": "STAR2020",
        "expiredate": "2025-08-05 04:40:28.0",
        "partner": "X",
        "nsp": "NAD"
    }
}
```

The **JSON** I actually expect:

```
{
    "STATUS": "SUCCESS",
    "DATA": {
        "ACTIVATION": {
            "aid": "0",
            "app": "OASIS_EDGE",
            "actkey": "STAR2020",
            "expiredate": "2025-08-05 04:40:28.0",
            "partner": "X",
            "nsp": "NAD"
        }
    }
}
```

Here is my **ActivationResponse.java** class responsible for creating the **JSON**:

```
public class ActivationResponse {   
    
    private String Status;
        
    public String getStatus()
    {
        return Status;
    }
    
    public void setStatus(String Status) {
        this.Status = Status;
    }
    
    @JsonProperty("DATA")   
        
    private ActivationModel activationData;
     
    
    public ActivationModel getActivationData() {
        return activationData;
    }

    public void setActivationData(ActivationModel activationData2) {
        this.activationData = activationData2;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you want activation under data, you need a class data with a field for activation, like the example below.

```java
class MyJson {
  private String Status;

  @JsonProperty("DATA")   
  private DataModel data;
};
 
class DataModel {
  @JsonProperty("ACTIVATION")   
  private ActivationModel activation;
};
```

Comment: Is it Correct:
public class ActivationResponse {  
 private String Status;  
 public String getStatus() {
  return Status;} 
 public void setStatus(String Status) {
  this.Status = Status;} 
    @JsonProperty("DATA")          
    private DataModel data;     
};
class DataModel {
   @JsonProperty("ACTIVATION")   
   private ActivationModel activationData;
   
   public ActivationModel getActivationData() {
         return activationData;
     }
     public void setActivationData(ActivationModel activationData2) {
         this.activationData = activationData2;
     }};

Answer (score 0):

1. Use **JsonNode** from **com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonNode** à la:

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonNode;

public class ActivationResponse {
    
    private String Status;

    private JsonNode activationData;
        
    public String getStatus() return Status;
    
    public void setStatus(String Status) this.Status = Status;  
    
    public ActivationModel getActivationData() return activationData;

    public void setActivationData(ActivationModel activationData2) {
        activationData = activationData2;
    }
}
```

2. Use the good 'ol **Map** from **java.util.Map** like so:

```
import java.util.Map;

public class ActivationResponse {
    
    private String Status;

    private Map<String, Object> activationData;
        
    public String getStatus() return Status;
    
    public void setStatus(String Status) this.Status = Status;  
    
    public ActivationModel getActivationData() return activationData;

    public void setActivationData(ActivationModel activationData2) {
        activationData = activationData2;
    }
}
```

I shamelessly borrowed from this [tutorial](https://www.baeldung.com/jackson-mapping-dynamic-object) (no affiliations)!